# How to determine if a file is in a removable drive or in the local drive

Tags: file, mfc, visual-c++, location

How do you determine if a file is on a removable drive or in the local drive in vc++?

Answer (score 4):

Call the [GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939(VS.85).aspx) API.

Edit:

```
UINT driveType = GetDriveType(lpFileName); 
if (driveType == DRIVE_FIXED) 
{ 
    /* fixed drive */ 
} 
else if (driveType == DRIVE_CDROM || driveType == DRIVE_REMOVABLE) 
{ 
    /* removable drive */ 
} 
else 
{ 
    /* other case e.g. network, RAM disk */ 
}
```

Comment: `UINT driveType = GetDriveType(lpFileName); if (driveType == DRIVE_FIXED) { /* fixed drive */ } else if (driveType == DRIVE_CDROM || driveType == DRIVE_REMOVABLE) { /* removable drive */ } else { /* other case e.g. network, RAM disk */ }`